# Where goes those messages not yet received in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

For example we have a basic node.js server <-> client comunicaciton.

A basic node.js server who sends each 500ms a message to the only o every one client connected with their respective socket initiated, the client is responding correctly to the heratbeat and receiving all the messages in time. But, imagine the client has a temporal connection lag (without closing socket), cpu overload, etc.. And cannot process nothing during 2secs or more.

In this situation, where goes all those the messages that are not yet received by the client?? 
They are stored in node? in any buffer or similar?

And viceversa? The client is sending every 500ms a message to the server (the server only listens without responding), but the server has a temporary connection issue or cpu  overhead during 2 or 3 secs..

Thanks in advice!! any information or aclaration will be welcomed

Javier

Comment: If the socket isn't interrupted, I'd imagine they head to the client anyways (or try). Best way, simulate the scenario and find out! :)

Comment: Yes, im just doing simulations, but is not dificult to clear.I see they sooner or later arrives, but im worry about the size of that middle space or whatever thing they are stored untill they arrives..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are stored in buffers, primarily in buffers provided by the OS kernel. Same thing on the receiving end for connections incoming to a node server.

Comment: OK, I was assuming. Only for curiosity you know the name of this buffers?

Comment: I think each OS has slightly different names and implementations, but I've usually just heard them referred to as "the kernel send buffer" for example.